# Getting bad access on setter method in swift

Tags: swift, swift2, exc-bad-access, setter

I have created swift class object and simply print their properties value.

[image: ViewController]

Which gives me error, like :

[image: Object class]

What is wrong here, something is missing ?

And yes, I have already tried solution which found and also referred some links. But can't find solution.

1. [swift setter causing exc_bad_access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31209615/swift-setter-causing-exc-bad-access)
2. [Swift - Custom setter on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828632/swift-custom-setter-on-property)
3. [Override a setter in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348049/override-a-setter-in-swift)

Comment: Could you please paste the code into the question instead of screenshots?

Comment: Your question is the exact duplicate of the first question you have mentioned and the solution with explanation is there.

Comment: Please show the code reflecting what you did after reading your first link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `name` setter creates an infinite recursion:

In the setter you are assigning again into the same variable, which again calls the setter, and so on.

Your code would work just with:

```
var name: String  // no need for setter or getter
var age: Int     // no need for setter or getter
```