# How can I extend protocol with private set?

Tags: swift, protocols, private, swift-protocols, swift-extensions

I'm writing a protocol that has a readOnly label. I want to extend it and give it a default implementation where the conforming type is a `UITextView`.

**Code:**

```
protocol CountingView {

    var keyboardLabel : UILabel {get}   
}

extension CountingView where Self : UITextView {

    var keyboardLabel : UILabel {
        get {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            return label
        }
        private (set) {
            keyboardLabel = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

However when I add the `private` before the `set` I get the following error.

> Expected 'get', 'set', 'willSet', or 'didSet' keyword to start an
>   accessor definition

<sub>I looked up other questions with this error but didn't find them related to mine.</sub>

Comment: Extensions *cannot* add stored properties. Your setter will call itself recursively. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063181/protocol-extension-in-swift-3.

Comment: @MartinR ummm. OK. You mean the answers here are incorrect?

Comment: Well, your *question* is how to make `private(set)` *compile.* The answers seem to be correct. My point is that even if you make it compile then your *implementation* of the setter `keyboardLabel = newValue` won't work as intended.

Answer (score 6):

You just have the private in the wrong place:

```
private(set) var keyboardLabel : UILabel {
    get {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }
    set {
        keyboardLabel = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: So you create a new label every time when calling the getter method? How does it work??

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your computed property `private` as this:

```
public private(set) var keyboardLabel : UILabel {
    get {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }

    set {
        keyboardLabel = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: God, you create a new label object when calling the getter every time?

Comment: @Itachi, it was not the question itself. There is better way of doing this. But the OP wanted to know how `private(set)` works in general.